# Write a program to input a string and then print all its words in reverse order without reversing the sentence (bluej ICSE java)

Tags: java, string, reverse, java-11, bluej

I have previously written programs to print the whole string in reverse order but this question asks u to reverse the word and yet retain its original position in the sentence.
Example input: "It is really dark"
Expected Output: "tI si yllaer krad"

I tried writing this program in bluej too ....as below:

```java
class reverse_each_word {

    public void disp(String s) {
        s = s + " ";
        String w = "", r = "";
        int sl = s.length();
        for (int i = 0; i < sl; i++) {
            char c = s.charAt(i);
            if (c != ' ') {
                w = w + c;
            } else
                for (int j = w.length() - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
                    r = r + w.charAt(j);
                }

            System.out.print(r + " ");
            w = "";
            r = "";
        }

    }

}
```

But due to some unknown reason, this is providing no output at all
I would be really grateful if someone could point out the problem in my code or write this program themselves. Also, keep in mind that I am just a beginner so pls don't use any other inbuilt functions except those strictly related to strings.

Comment: Can anybody tell me why my program isn't working

Answer (score 2):

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String str = "It is really dark";
    System.out.println(reverseWords(str));  // tI si yllaer krad
}

public static String reverseWords(String str) {
    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder(str.length());

    for (String word : str.split("\\s+")) {
        if (buf.length() != 0)
            buf.append(' ');

        for (int i = word.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            buf.append(word.charAt(i));
    }

    return buf.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
public void disp(String s) {  
    // you will start from last character, all the way back to first  
    for (int i = s.length(); i>=0; i++) {  
        // here you will print out character at the index, right to left  
        System.out.print(s.charAt(i));  
    }  
}
```

Comment: Can you give a hint (or example) how that be  should done?

Comment: Yea actually I just started using stackoverflow. Could you please give me some guidance on how to actually give a good answer? Do I need to  give them a sample code or just explain to them the logic and let them figure it out, coz I think that way they can learn better.

Comment: Anything...u might give me a algorithm or a program although in my case a program would be much more helpful